# ImportError: No module named when module is there

Tags: python, python-3.x

I usually run python2 but I am playing with python3. Right now I am confused as to why I am getting this error.

When I run the command `./test_web_events.py` in the `tests` directory, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_web_events.py", line 21, in <module>
    import qe.util.scratchstore as scratchstore
ImportError: No module named 'qe'
```

However my project structure has `qe` directory in it:

```
/python_lib
   Makefile
   /qe
      __init__.py
      /tests
         __init__.py
         test_web_events.py
      /util
         __init__.py
         scratchstore.py
      /trinity
         __init__.py
```

I tried moving my `/tests` directory into `/python_lib` but I am still getting the same error:

```
MTVL1289dd026:python_lib bli1$ ls
Makefile    qe      rundata     setup.sh    tests
MTVL1289dd026:python_lib bli1$ python3 tests/test_web_events.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/test_web_events.py", line 21, in <module>
    import qe.util.scratchstore as scratchstore
ImportError: No module named 'qe'
```

Here is my `sys.path` for python2

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

`sys.path` for python3

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

Comment: It says up there it is in the test_web_events.py

Comment: is there an __init__.py file in python_lib dir ?

Comment: @Andrew_Lvov That has nothing to do with it, he isn't trying to import `python_lib`

Comment: @mattm, you're right.

Comment: Andrew_Lvov meant a `__init__.py` file (it can be empty).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `/python_lib` is not in Python path. The behavior is the same on both Python 2 and 3.

In general, [do not run scripts from within (inside) a Python package](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap), run them from the top-level directory instead:

```
/python_lib$ python -m qe.tests.test_web_events
```

Thus `/python_lib` is in Python path and `/python_lib/qe/tests` is not. It assumes that there is `tests/__init__.py` file.

Do not modify `sys.path` manually. It may lead to subtle bugs related to importing modules. There are better alternatives e.g., if you don't want to run the scripts from `/python_lib`, just install the development version:

```
(your_virtualenv)/python_lib$ pip install -e .
```

Comment: Still getting the same error after I moved `/tests` into `/python_lib` =/ http://dpaste.com/39PBWDC

Comment: do you run it from `/python_lib`? If you print `sys.path`; you should see this directory in it. Update you question and include the full traceback – you can't get the same error.

Comment: yes I did run it in `python_lib` question is updated!

Comment: @Liondancer: It is my mistake. I've removed the broken `python tests/test_web_events.py` command. It requires something like [`_preamble.py`](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/bin/_preamble.py) (in your case search for `qe` instead of `twisted`).

Comment: Not really sure what this implies =/ `MTVL1289dd026:python_lib bli1$ python3 -m qe.tests.test_web_events.py 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for 'qe.tests.test_web_events.py' (<class 'AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__')`

Comment: `__path__` is an attribute supported by Python packages. Make sure there are `__init__.py` files present to mark packages.

Comment: hmmm I have `__init__.py` in `/python_lib` but I am getting that error still =/

Comment: you should not have `__init__.py` in python_lib. It is not a Python package. qe and qe.tests are packages.

Comment: @Liondancer: then `/python_lib$ python -m qe.tests.test_web_events` should work unless there are circular imports in `__init__.py` (absolute imports such as `import qe.something` should be ok though).

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely because you haven't added `/python_lib/qe` to your `PYTHONPATH`.

When you try to import a module, the interpreter will look for it only in a certain number of places, you cannot arbitrarily try to import a module from anywhere.

The most common ways are to have a package installed via `pip`, to have the module sitting in the same directory as the `.py` file, or to have added the path to that module to the `PYTHONPATH`.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

It seems like the latter case is most likely what you want to do. This is going to be dependent on your OS, but googling it should be straightforward.

Comment: `sys.path` is not the `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `__init__.py` file in all your package folders so that you tructure looks like

```
/python_lib
   Makefile
   /qe
      /tests
         test_web_events.py
      /util
         __init__.py                <------------ create this file
         scratchstore.py
      /trinity
      __init__.py
```

and then the you `cd` to `python_lib` folder and run ``export PYTHONPATH=`pwd```

Comment: Then just fix the PYTHONPATH. by running `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/python_lib`.

Answer (score -1):

Just `#!/usr/bin/env python` add this to your all scripts. Make sure it's on the top.Like;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import qe
```

I assume you **added Python 3 to path**, if you did, the only problem is this. You do **not** need `init.py` or sys.path or anything. This line already finding Python path automatically if you **added** Python 3 to path, if Python 2 still on the path then it's normal you got error.

Comment: All of them has this? Are you sure?

Comment: @Liondancer You are doing something wrong then. I worked with `modules` a lot, and this was the problem all the time. Make sure your all of scripts has this at the top.

Comment: I think it has to do with the python 2 and 3 paths =/ I usually use 2 but i pulled a project and its written in 3. I know I have 3 installed but im not sure how to switch back and forth